# piecewise function construction with two solutions for one variable

Tags: function-construction

i would like to define function shown below:

[image]

i try using

```
n[fi_] := Piecewise[{
            {-b*ProductLog[-1,a], n[fi]>=b},
            {-b*ProductLog[a], n[fi]=<b}
          }]
```

where a is a function of fi, but i get recursion error. What would be the correct way to define it?

Comment: Note that your first branch in piecewise is probably missing something in the definition. There seems to be a dangling “*”

Comment: Are you sure that the definition of the function is correct? I can't quite wrap my head around what this means. You define the function $n(\phi)$ but then also the conditions depend on the function $n(\phi)$? (Usually you would put conditions on the value of $\phi$.) Perhaps you could provide some context?

Comment: i am trying to model laser pulse. ϕ is the photon density, n is population inversion density, and n_th is the threshold value of population inversion density. ϕ goes from zero to maximum, and then from maximum decays to zero, while n(ϕ) is monotonously changing changing from n_initial to n_final. so for every ϕ there are two solutions of n. n(ϕ) acts as LambertW[a] until threhsold n_th is reached, n(ϕ) changes its function to LambertW[-1,a] when the function surpasses n_th. I thought over night that it would probably work if i made conditions with max value of ϕ(n) as its probably defines n_th